# Variadic template folding program fails in gcc9

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++17, variadic-templates

I got the following program working as expected with -std=c++14 and -std=c++1z using g++ 8.3. But, when I upgraded to g++ 9.1, it works only when -std=c++14, but not for higher versions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#if __cplusplus >= 201500L // C++17 or higher

template <typename... Args>
auto sum(Args&&... args) 
{
    return (0 + args);// + ... );
}

#elif __cplusplus >= 201402L // C++14

auto sum() { return 0; }
template <typename T>
auto sum(T&& t) { return t; }
template <typename T, typename... Rest>
auto sum(T&& t, Rest&&... r) 
{
    return t + sum(forward<Rest>(r)...);
}

#else
#error "***You need C++14 or higher to compile this program***"
#endif

int main()
{
    cout << sum() << " result of 2 + 3=>" << sum(2, 3) <<
        " result of 12+15+18=>" << sum(12, 15, 18) << "\n";
#if __cplusplus >= 201500L // C++17 or higher
    cout << "Compiled as C++17 program\n";
#else
    cout << "Compiled as C++14 program\n";
#endif
}
```

g++ 9.1 generates the following error message (with a host of its siblings), when I used -std=c++1z, c++17 or c++2a:

```
In function 'auto sum(Args&& ...)':
error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
   12 |     return (0 + args);// + ... );
      |            ~~~^~~~~~~
note:         'args'
In function 'int main()':
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'void') 
   32 |     cout << sum() << " result of 2 + 3=>" << sum(2, 3) <<
      |     ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~
      |     |          |   
      |     |          void
      |     std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

Comment: I cannot confirm g++ 8.3 erroneously accepting that as C++1z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(0 + args)` is not a valid fold expression.

You want `(0 + ... + args)`.

---

Also, for me GCC 8.3 (with `-std=c++1z`) [rejects](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0A%23if+__cplusplus+%3E%3D+201500L+//+C%2B%2B17+or+higher%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Aauto+sum(Args%26%26...+args)+%0A%7B%0A++++return+(0+%2B+args)%3B//+%2B+...+)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23elif+__cplusplus+%3E%3D+201402L+//+C%2B%2B14%0A%0Aauto+sum()+%7B+return+0%3B+%7D%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aauto+sum(T%26%26+t)+%7B+return+t%3B+%7D%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename...+Rest%3E%0Aauto+sum(T%26%26+t,+Rest%26%26...+r)+%0A%7B%0A++++return+t+%2B+sum(forward%3CRest%3E(r)...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23else%0A%23error+%22***You+need+C%2B%2B14+or+higher+to+compile+this+program***%22%0A%23endif%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+sum()+%3C%3C+%22+result+of+2+%2B+3%3D%3E%22+%3C%3C+sum(2,+3)+%3C%3C%0A++++++++%22+result+of+12%2B15%2B18%3D%3E%22+%3C%3C+sum(12,+15,+18)+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%23if+__cplusplus+%3E%3D+201500L+//+C%2B%2B17+or+higher%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+%22Compiled+as+C%2B%2B17+program%5Cn%22%3B%0A%23else%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+%22Compiled+as+C%2B%2B14+program%5Cn%22%3B%0A%23endif%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'1',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) your code.

Comment: The important part is the assertion that it was accepted as C++1z for g++ 8.3, I think.

Comment: Thanks. With this suggested correction, the code compiles properly in g++ 9.1 as c++17 program.